# SQL SELECT query, combine matching rows, using one column value where equal or concatenating where not

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble coming up with a query that does as the title describes.
Basically, here's an example table

```
+-------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Class | Sect | otherCol1 | otherCol2 | otherCol3 |
+-------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  abc  | 100  |     3     |    4      |     5     |
|  def  | 100  |     5     |    6      |     7     |
|  abc  | 100  |     3     |   loco    |    guys   |
|  def  | 100  |    guys   |    6      |     77    |
+-------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I would like the result to be

```
+-------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Class | Sect | otherCol1 | otherCol2 | otherCol3 |
+-------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  abc  | 100  |     3     |    4loco  |    5guys  |
|  def  | 100  |   5guys   |    6      |     777   |
+-------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

It is important that the order of the combined elements remain consistent. For instance, if the new row says "4loco", it should say "5guys". If it says "loco4" then it should say "guys5".

The MySQL query that I have at the moment seems to be close to what I want, but it fails to concatenate all the matches. Some columns will remain unconcatenated while others will concatenate appropriately. It also doesn't maintain consistent ordering across the columns that it concatenates for a given row.

Here is a simplified version of my query that does the same thing as what I am running but with fewer columns than I am actually working with:

```
SELECT 
    IF(
        t1.Class = t2.Class, 
        t1.Class, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t1.Class SEPARATOR ' ')
    ), 
    IF(
        t1.Sect = t2.Sect, 
        t1.Sect, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t1.Sect SEPARATOR ' ')
    ), 
    IF(
        t1.otherCol1 = t2.otherCol1, 
        t1.otherCol1, 
        GROuP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t1.otherCol1 SEPARATOR ' ')
    ), 
    IF(
        t1.otherCol2 = t2.otherCol2, 
        t1.otherCol2, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t1.otherCol2 SEPARATOR ' ')
    ), 
    IF(
        t1.otherCol3 = t2.otherCol3, t1.otherCol3, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t1.otherCol3 SEPARATOR ' ')
    ) 
FROM sample_sheet t1 
JOIN sample_sheet t2 
    ON t1.Sect = t2.Sect 
    AND t1.Class = t2.Class 
GROUP BY t1.Sect, t1.Class
```

All columns that are not `Class` and `Sect` are candidates for concatenation depending on their values. I only need the concatenation to occur if the values are not equal, hence the `if` statements.

Comment: Which version of MySQL? `'abd'` is a typo, I suppose?

Comment: Preserving the order means we can get a value multifold in a concatenation. Let's add a row `abc | 100 | cool | 4 | guys`. Is `abc | 100 | 3cool | 4loco4 | 5guys` a valid solution then? (Preserving the order forces `4loco4` which contains the 4 twice.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes, `'abd'` is a typo, it should read `'abc'`. And no, your scenario would not be the valid outcome. You are correct that (for the order preservation) the underlying rule is that whatever order is imposed on one column must also be imposed on the other columns. The order in which the concatenation occurs cannot be random across columns, which is the behavior that my query seems to achieve. But any duplicate values in the matched rows must not be concatenated, only the unique values should be concatenated.

Comment: So you'd want to supress a four and end up with 4loco probably, as the 4 appears in the first and third row and you'd take the minimum position. This may require a lot of work. A user defined aggregate function maybe? Or unpivot the columns, aggregate and pivot them again? Don't know. Your best bet may be to select * and use a programming language then to do the aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate and use `group_concat(distinct ...)`.

For the order to remain consistent, you need a column (or a combination of columns) that can be used to order the records; I cannot see such column in your data, but I assumes that it exists, and I called it `id`.

```
select 
    class, 
    sect, 
    group_concat(distinct otherCol1 order by id separator '') otherCol1,
    group_concat(distinct otherCol2 order by id separator '') otherCol2,
    group_concat(distinct otherCol3 order by id separator '') otherCol3
from mytable
group by 
    class, 
    sect
```

Comment: What does your example accomplish that my query doesn't? As you can see, I am already aggregating and using group_concat(). The problem is that it is not concatenating correctly based on my conditional statements, nor is the order of concatenation being consistently preserved.

Comment: @JohnManos: there are several important differences, notably (1) my query does proper aggregation, while in yours, not all non-aggregated columns appear in the `group by` clause (2) it is much simpler: no `join`, no `if`, etc

Comment: @JohnManos: please test it and see if it produces the expected results.

Comment: the problem is that it is over-simplified. First of all, otherCol1 does not belong in the `group by`, all columns that are not class and sect are candidates for aggregation depending on their values. Second, I only need the concatenation to occur if the values are not equal, hence the `if` statements. I will update the question description to clarify.

Comment: @JohnManos: I updated my answer as per your updated OP.

Comment: That did it very cleanly, thank you! The addition of an id column was a very good idea, and for my usage case, was particularly easy to implement.